# Unavailability of package razorpay/omnipay-razorpay

Tags: composer-php, razorpay, omnipay

My composer.json file is as follows:

```
{
    "name": "razorpay/razorpay",
    "description": "Razorpay PHP Client Library",
    "keywords": ["razorpay", "api", "php", "client"],
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Abhay Rana",
            "email": "nemo@razorpay.com",
            "homepage": "https://captnemo.in",
            "role": "Developer"
        },
        {
            "name": "Shashank Kumar",
            "email": "shashank@razorpay.com",
            "role": "Developer"
        }
    ],
    "support": {
        "email": "contact@razorpay.com",
        "issues": "https://github.com/Razorpay/razorpay-php/issues",
        "source": "https://github.com/Razorpay/razorpay-php"
    },
    "homepage": "https://docs.razorpay.com",
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.0",
        "rmccue/requests": "^2.0",
        "ext-json": "*",
    "razorpay/omnipay-razorpay": "~2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "raveren/kint": "1.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Razorpay\\Api\\": "src/",
            "Razorpay\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        },
        "files" : ["Deprecated.php"]
    }
}
```

the error when I use

> $composer update

is as follows:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires razorpay/omnipay-razorpay, it could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 2
    - phpunit/phpunit[9.0.0, ..., 9.2.6] require php ^7.3 -> your php version (5.6.40) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit[9.3.0, ..., 9.3.8] require php ^7.3 || ^8.0 -> your php version (5.6.40) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit[9.3.9, ..., 9.5.20] require php >=7.3 -> your php version (5.6.40) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Root composer.json requires phpunit/phpunit ^9 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[9.0.0, ..., 9.5.20].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.
 - It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it
```

For clarification purpose where do I update

```
{
    "require": {
        "`razorpay/omnipay-razorpay`": "~2.0"
    }
}
```

as per the instruction given in https://github.com/razorpay/omnipay-razorpay
Do we have to update it in composer.json file available in razorpay-php file (https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-php/releases/) or create a new composer.json file and add information based on composer JSON schema.

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect all packages that you can install without any custom settings on https://packagist.org. When searching for `razorpay/omnipay-razorpay` on that site, it does not list this package. You should contact the maintainers of that package about this, as they need to publish the package on Packagist. If it should not be available there, but in any other package repository, they need to update their documentation about this.

---

Anyways, their package has not seen any substantial update since years. I would assume that development on their side has ended, and you should check for any third-party connector